# Add data to a Table<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a property on a class that happens to be a `Table<T>`. How do I add an item to this?

Comment: `System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity>` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx

Comment: Sorry, didn't kow there was more than one table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [`Table<TEntity>.InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx).